# docbook webhelp part toc blocked by possibly a div block

Tags: docbook-5

When generating webhelp from ant script the toc for part element is blocked by a box. This box appears to be connected with toc in left pane. When toc pane is resized the box in main window also resizes. Anyone experience this and know how to fix. Using sample build.xml and properties file in docbook webhelp folder with no special customizing.

[image: Part TOC blocked]

Answer (score 0):

I switched to another jquery ui theme instead of the default redmond theme and commented out the embedded style section in webhelp-common.xsl file. Solved the problem. Didn't track down cause of default theme.